# Get 2 integers separated by space from string

Tags: java

Let's say I have an input formatted as "a b" and I want to extract a and b. For example, if my input is `10 15` I want to set `a` as 10 and `b` as 15. I usually do this by using `StringTokenizer` like so:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
int a = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
int b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

Is there any way where I can do this in a much shorter piece of code?

Comment: That is short and simple and easy to read. How would you expect to 1) parse a string  2) assign values to 2 variable in less that 3 statements? Even if you could do it in less statements it doesn't mean you should since the code will become unreadable and much harder to debug.

Comment: If you're looking for short, unreadable code, choose something other than Java

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to an `int[]` by using `String.split(String)` and then *streaming* that to an `IntStream` by mapping. Like,

```
int[] vals = Stream.of(str.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
int a = vals[0], b = vals[1];
```

And you ***can*** use a comma to separate assignments. Of course, your original version code use that trick to eliminate a line. However, now we can eliminate `a` and `b` by using `vals[0]` and `vals[1]`. Without further context I wouldn't necessarily recommend that.